# find and copy files using input list and partial file paths

Tags: find, cp, xargs

I have a list of filenames `names.list` which contains names only. These files are scattered throughout my system in various sub folders but the structure is generally

```
uniquename/uniquename2/spades/filtered/filename
```

The constant is `spades/filtered`

I have used the [following command](https://serverfault.com/questions/212439/linux-mv-or-cp-specific-files-from-a-text-list-of-files) when moving files from one directory

```
xargs -a file_list.txt cp -t /path/to/dest
```

And I spotted this thread on using [wildcard/ partial file name](https://superuser.com/questions/400078/how-can-i-search-a-file-by-its-name-and-partial-path)s

```
find . -path \*content/docs/file.xml
```

And I tried combining them like so

```
find . -path \*spades/filtered/ | xargs -a names.list cp -t $HOME/destination/
```

But I get the following error:

```
cp: cannot stat `filename': No such file or directory
```

tldr: I want to copy files using and input list of names only and partial file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the filenames via a for-loop and append them to the find pattern, copy with exec handle:

```
for i in $(<names.list)
do
    find . -path \*spades/filtered/"$i" -type f -exec cp -t "$HOME/destination/" {} \;;
done
```

**Edit**: Thanks to Rakesh Sharma`s answer, substituting the loop body with:

```
find . -mindepth 5 -maxdepth 5 -path "*/spades/filtered/$i" -type f -exec cp -t "$HOME/destination/" {} +;
```

speeds things up.

Comment: Hi FloHe, I want to search within the partial directory path the files which are in my list.

Comment: @AudileF Why do you want to search within the partial dir path when the list file already have them with the partial path as a constant you mentioned earlier on?

Comment: No my list is just names only. There is no path within the list. I see my original question is misleading. Ill change it now.

Comment: @AudileF: So you have them without the partial dir path prefix in the file names.list? But then it isn't clear in which partial dir path to search for the individual files.

Comment: @AudileF: This means running through all directories and look if the named file is there, if yes copy it?

Comment: Thats right. Look in directories that look like `spades/filtered`and copy if on this list.

Comment: Its very slow but it appears to be working.

Comment: @FloHe is it possible to incorporate the -maxdepth option into the command?

Comment: @AudileF You could make the following changes to speed things up; `find . -mindepth 5 -maxdepth 5 -path "*/spades/filtered/$i" -type f -exec cp -t "$HOME/destination/" {} +;` where you are basically giving a chunk of files to cp rather than just 1 and the min/max-depths allow find to jump right in to the right hierarchy rather than recurse it's way through.

Answer (score 0):

You could do away with the `for` loop and do everything within `xargs`:

```
xargs -a names.list -L 1 -I @ find . -path \*/spades/filtered/@ -type f -exec cp -fpvt "$HOME/destination/" {} +
```

Assuming GNU xargs, find, and cp utilities.

`-a` will read the filename a line at a time.

`-L 1` option makes `xargs` pass one newline-separated argument to find.

`-I @` option will condense that argument in the symbol `@` which can be stuck in the utility invoked by `xargs`, in this case, `find`. More specifically, the `-path` option of `find` is modified by the `@` symbol for every line of names.list read.